# How to find the following number using modular arithmetic

Tags: modular-arithmetic

Suppose I have a number $x$ such that,
$$
x \equiv 31^{29}  \text{ (mod 57)}
$$
How can I find $x$ using properties of modular arithmetic. Will it involve a special theorem?

Comment: $57=3*19$ so you can reduce it to solving that equation mod 3 and 19. From there use Fermat’s little theorem to reduce to exponent and the rest is probably just a little bit of brute force (for the 19 case in particular).

Comment: Cf. [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/81228/how-do-i-compute-ab-bmod-c-by-hand) and [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2033639/mod-of-numbers-with-large-exponents-modular-order-reduction)

Comment: @TokenToucan Binary method would be better than shear brute force, and could honestly be applied directly with fair ease.

Comment: I am not familiar with the binary method. "Brute force" in this situation is actually quite easy. It isn't necessary at all for the mod 3 part, and the mod 19 part should only take a couple small computations to simplify. Perhaps post your technique as an answer for others unfamiliar with it.

Comment: @TokenToucan I got $31^{29} \equiv 31 $ mod $3$, but after using Fermat's Little Theorem how do i simplify $31^{18} \equiv 1$ mod $19$

Comment: @HackerBoss: In this case, as $31\equiv 1\bmod 3$, I think it simplifies greatly the computations if one has to do them by hand.

Answer (score 1):

Here is one solution. By the Chinese Remainder Theorem, one reduces to solving the same equation mod 3 and mod 19, as we can patch those together at the end.

Mod 3: the easy case
$$31^{29} = 1^{29} = 1$$

Mod 19: just a long chain of combining small groups of multiplications and reducing mod 19 as frequently as possible to keep the arithmetic easy
$$31^{29} = 31^{11} = 12^{11} = 12*(12)^{2*5} = 12*(144)^5 = 12*(11)^5= 12*11*(11)^4$$
$$=12*11*(121)^2 = 12*11*7^2 = 12*11*49 = 12*11*11 = 12*7 = 84 = 8$$

So altogether the solution is congruent to 1 mod 3 and 8 mod 19, which we see lifts to 46 mod 57 (as usual for the CRT, just start with one solution, 8 mod 19, and add multiples of 19 until it is congruent to 1 mod 3).

Sometimes there are tricks to speed things up but these numbers look sort of "random" to me.

Comment: We could use $\bmod 19\!:\ 31^6\equiv 1\,$ by $\,31^3\equiv (-7)^3\equiv -1\,$ so 
$31^{29}\equiv 31^5\equiv -7(-8)^2\equiv 8\ \ $

Comment: Ah good eye, -7 would have been easier to handle than 12.